# How to prorate a monthly billing amount when service was only performed for 13 calendar days in a month?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a problem where I need to prorate a monthly billing amount by actual days of service rendered.  I have a Sumifs built into the cell that needs to be prorated but I am unclear how to pull the reduced amount without altering the data pulled by the Sumifs. Can anyone help me?  Thank you

```
=SUMIFS('ACD Data'!CF:CF,'ACD Data'!AD:AD,A26,'ACD Data'!F:F,C26,'ACD Data'!C:C,"3/1/2023",'ACD Data'!CH:CH,D26)
```

CF is the column where I pull the prorate amounts.  AD is the unique identifier. FF is the branch code that provided the service.  CC is the impact date.

Below is the prorated function I created.

```
=[@[IMPACT AMT]]/30*ABS((31-DAY([@[IMPACT_DATE]])))
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a MINIMAL mock dataset and expected output for that dataset.